# T SQL Cte delete where group by is greater than 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm using SQL Server 2016.  I have the below table:

```
SKU     Mkt   Week   Cost   Code
ABC     05     1      10     100
ABC     05     2      12     100

DEF     05     3      20     100
DEF     05     3      25     125

XYZ     08     1      10     100
XYZ     08     2      12     100
XZY     08     2      14     125
```

This is the desired result:

```
SKU     Mkt   Week   Cost   Code
ABC     05     1      10     100
ABC     05     2      12     100

DEF     05     3      25     125

XYZ     08     1      10     100
XZY     08     2      14     125
```

So if a SKU\Mkt\Week\Cost exist more than once, I want to keep the record where code = 125 and delete the row where the code is 100.

I'm using the below Cte:

```
  ;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY SKU, Mkt, Week
                                    ORDER BY SKU, Mkt, Week)
    FROM [table]
    WHERE code = 100
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```

However, the Cte doesnot delete anything -what am I missing?

Comment: check select statement result first and you see you will get no result, therefore, it is not deleting the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the query and sample data you have provided, You need to note to this section of the cte inner query:

```
WHERE code = 100
```

when this filter applied you have the following data:

```
SKU     Mkt   Week   Cost   Code
ABC     05     1      10     100
ABC     05     2      12     100

DEF     05     3      20     100
```

which will get the 1 as `Row_Number()`'s output!, so running the following query will not effect any rows:

```
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```

To achieve the desired result you need to remove the WHERE section in CTE's inner query.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY SKU, Mkt, Week
             ORDER BY SKU, Mkt, Week, Cost DESC) --Code/Cost DESC <==== Note this too
    FROM [table]
    --WHERE code = 100  <========== HERE, I've commented it
)
DELETE FROM CTE
WHERE RN > 1
```

You need to also add the `Cost DESC` or `Code Desc` to `Row_Number()`'s `Order By` section.

Comment: @Michael may I ask you to UpVote it too, if it really help you? Regards

Comment: Worth noting that this solution is somewhat limited to the sample data set. If, for example, you had another record like ('DEF','05',3,25,200), then the resulting DEF record will be for the 200 code and not the 125 code.  If this scenario would not occur, then there is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ranking function will be evaluated in the select statement , which means the where clause  `WHERE code = 100` is evaluated before  ROW_NUMBER() and so it has already removed the rows with code 125. Use order by Code as well and then apply the `code=100` check when deleting from the CTE

```
 ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT  *,
                RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY SKU, Mkt, Week
                                        ORDER BY SKU, Mkt, Week,Code DESC)
        FROM tt1
    )

    DELETE FROM CTE
    WHERE RN > 1
AND CODE = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query to get the desired result  -

**Sample data and Query**

```
  Declare  @Table table
 (SKU varchar(20), Mkt int, [Week] int, Cost int, Code int)

  Insert into @Table
  values
  ( 'ABC',     05   ,  1,      10   ,  100),
  ( 'ABC' ,    05  ,   2 ,     12  ,   100),
  ('DEF'     ,05    , 3    ,  20    , 100),
  ('DEF'     ,05    , 3      ,25    , 125),
  ('XYZ'     , 08  ,   1      ,10  ,   100),
  ('XYZ'    ,  08  ,   2      ,12  ,   100),
  ('XYZ'     , 08,     2      ,14,     125)

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY SKU, Mkt, Week
                      ORDER BY SKU, Mkt, Week, code desc)
    FROM @Table
)
delete from Cte where RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with moving your Where statement, I believe you also want a second cte to work with the records you are identifying...  In the following your first cte identifies the duplicate records while the second cte isolates them so you can perform your delete against those SKUs

Table

```
Create Table #tbl
(
SKU VarChar(10),
Mkt VarChar(10),
Week Int,
Cost Int,
Code Int
)
Insert Into #tbl Values
('ABC','05',1,10,100),
('ABC','05',2,12,100),
('DEF','05',3,20,100),
('DEF','05',3,25,125),
('XYZ','08',1,10,100),
('XYZ','08',2,12,100),
('XYZ','08',2,14,125)
```

Query

```
  ;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY SKU, Mkt, Week
                                    ORDER BY SKU, Mkt, Week)
    FROM #tbl
    --WHERE code = 100
)       
, cte1 As
(
     Select sku from cte where rn > 1
)
DELETE c FROM CTE c inner join cte1 c1 On c.SKU = c1.SKU
WHERE c.Code = 100
```

Select * From #tbl

Result (Your 'desired result' example removed an XYZ record where the week was not duplicated?)

```
SKU Mkt Week    Cost    Code
ABC 05  1       10      100
ABC 05  2       12      100
DEF 05  3       25      125
XYZ 08  1       10      100
XYZ 08  2       12      100
XZY 08  2       14      125
```

Answer (score -1):

Your CTE statement is only considering rows with code = 100. If you remove it, then CTE will rank based on all rows from the table. Using this, first find out which combination of  have multiple rows. Then, among these  combinations, identify rows with code = 100 and delete them.

```
create table #e1
(
SKU varchar(50)
,Mkt varchar(50)
,_Week int
,Cost int
,_code int
)

insert into #e1(SKU, Mkt, _Week, Cost, _code)
select 'ABC',     '05',     1,      10,     100 UNION
SELECT 'ABC',     '05',     2,      12,     100 union
SELECT 'DEF',     '05',     3,      20,     100 UNION
SELECT 'DEF',     '05',     3,      25,     125 UNION
SELECT 'XYZ',     '08',     1,      10,     100 UNION
SELECT 'XYZ',     '08',     2,      12,     100 UNION
SELECT 'XZY',     '08',     2,      14,     125 


delete s
from
#e1 s
JOIN
(
    SELECT  SKU, Mkt, _Week 
    FROM #e1
    group by 
    SKU, Mkt, _Week 
    having count(1) > 1
) m
ON
s.SKU = m.sku and s.mkt = m.mkt and s._Week = m._Week
WHERE s._code = 100
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Create table #tab1 (SKU varchar(50),Mkt varchar(50),[Week] varchar(50),Cost varchar(50),Code varchar(50))

insert into #tab1
select 'ABC','05','1','10','100'
union
select 'ABC','05','2','12','100'    
union
select 'DEF','05','3','20','100'   
union
select 'DEF','05','3','25','125'  
union
select 'XYZ','08','1','10','100'    
union
select 'XYZ','08','2','12','100'   
union
select 'XYZ','08','2','14','125'  



delete t from #tab1 t
inner join (select t1.SKU,t1.Mkt,t1.[Week],t1.Cost as Cost,t1.Code  as Code,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by t1.SKU,t1.Mkt,t1.[Week] order by t1.Cost desc,t1.Code desc ) as rno
from #tab1 t1
) c on c.SKU = t.SKU and c.Mkt = t.Mkt and c.Cost = t.Cost and c.[Week] = t.[Week] and  c.Code = t.Code
 where c.rno = 2
```

select * from #tab1

Output:

```
SKU Mkt Week    Cost    Code
ABC 05  1         10    100
ABC 05  2         12    100
DEF 05  3         25    125
XYZ 08  1         10    100
XYZ 08  2         14    125
```